# Не получается отфильтрованным пользователям поменять значения в профиле

Tags: php, битрикс

Помогите решить проблему: при отфильтровывании пользователя по группе пытаюсь по условию (если дата активности пользователя в группе меньше текущей даты) в его профиле убрать галочку с чекбокса:

```html
$filter = Array();
        $arParameters = array(
            'SELECT' => array("UF_*")
        );
        $reg = CUser::GetList(($by="id"), ($order="asc"), $filter, $arParameters); // выбираем пользователей
        while($rsUsers = $reg->NavNext()){
            $arUses[] = $rsUsers;
            $res = CUser::GetUserGroupList($rsUsers['ID']);
            while ($arGroup = $res->Fetch()){
                if ($arGroup['GROUP_ID'] == '22') {
                    $rsUsers['GRUPP_LIENT_DATA_TO'] = $arGroup;
     $arClientCvalif[] = $rsUsers;
     print "<pre>"; print_r($rsUsers); print "</pre>";
        }
   }
  }
if ($arClientCvalif) {
            foreach ($arClientCvalif as $arItemClient) {
            if ($arItemClient['GRUPP_LIENT_DATA_TO']['DATE_ACTIVE_TO']) {
            if (MakeTimeStamp(date('d.m.Y H:i:s')) <= MakeTimeStamp($arItemClient['GRUPP_LIENT_DATA_TO']['DATE_ACTIVE_TO'])*1 ) {
$user = new CUser;
$fields = Array(
  "ACTIVE" => "N",
  );
$user->Update($ID, $fields);

   }
  }
  }
}
```

При выполнении этого кода, галочка не убирается((

Comment: Так а чекбокс активности сам спадает если дата активности меньше. Это же стандартный функционал. Или вы говорите о своем чекбоксе который пользовательский добавили в профиль клиента?

Comment: @Nikolaj Sarry дал ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если вы задали пользователю дату активности, то флаг активности снимется автоматически если дата активности будет меньше текущей.

Answer (score -1):

Разобрался, проблема была в `$user->Update($ID, $fields);`
Функция `Update` должна обновлять пользователя не с глобальным ID а с id выбранном из массива`$arItemClient['ID']`